# Is this scraper site in violation of StackExchange's attribution requirements?

Tags: discussion, legal, licensing, creative-commons

Compare:

- http://dluat.com/prevent-tty-fallback-when-x-fails/
- [Prevent TTY fallback when X fails](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/8185/2264)

We're all aware that our content is licensed under CC-BY-SA.  DL-AUT is not licensing its content thusly (content falls under the `© 2015 dluat.com` at the bottom) and is also implicitly claiming authorship of the content (going by `Dicol` – search that word on the page).  There is a `Source link` available at the bottom of each post (though not on any [listings page](http://dluat.com/category/faqs/technology/stack-overflow/)), but the common-sense implication is still there.